# How to verify case-insensitive filepath in Ansible

Tags: ansible, filepath, case-insensitive

My server has the below path where the hostname i.e "myhost1" folder can either be in upper case or lower case as shown in example below.

> /app/cell/myhost1_sales075/nodes/Node009/servers/server.xml

or the path could be in upper case hostname like below

> /app/cell/MYHOST1_sales075/nodes/Node009/servers/server.xml

Below is my playbook which checks if the path exists else it will fail.

Note: ansible_hostname may either return myhost1 (lowercase) or MYHOST1 (uppercase)

```
- name: check if Path is valid
  shell: "ls -l /app/cell/{{ ansible_hostname }}*/nodes/*Node*/servers/server.xml"
  ignore_errors: yes
  register: shorewall

- fail:
    msg: Path or server name is invalid. Kindly enter correct PATH. Exiting Now...
  when: shorewall.rc != 0
```

The problem I face is that my check is case sensitive when I want it to be case-insensitive. Thus my playbook should not fail if hostname is either upper or lowercase along with the wildcard "*"

Can you please let me know what changes I need to do in my playbook for the Path check to be case-insensitive ?

Comment: You have to check for both paths and exit if none of them exist. You can do that with a loop on both paths on the first task. Meanwhile, you should consider using [the `stat` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) rather than `shell` to check if files exist.

Comment: Can you tell me what the when condition should be? Because, if i loop for both lower and upper case path one of them will always fail so variable.rc will always be !=0. Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: this is only answering your direct question. Meanwhile you should consider reviewing your current script and use the [`stat`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/stat_module.html) module to check for file presence instead of ignoring errors on `ls` launched in a `shell`

---

The solution below will check both path, then extract all the `rc` fields in your `results` registered var with [`json_query`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) and check if at least one of them returned `0`

**Prereq**: `pip install jmespath` on the controller machine (required by `json_query` filter).

```yaml
---
- name: Verify upper/lower path with ls in shell (bad)
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

    - name: Check my path
      shell: "ls -l /tmp/{{ item }}"
      register: my_path
      ignore_errors: yes
      loop:
        - "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
        - "{{ inventory_hostname | upper }}"

    - name: Fail if path does not exists
      fail:
        msg: path does not exists
      when: 0 not in (my_path | json_query('results[].rc[]'))
```

---

*Update*

Using `json_query` might have been an overkill here. You can get the same result with core filters:

```yaml
      when: 0 not in (my_path.results | map(attribute="rc'))
```

Comment: that perfectly answers my question. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: do we really need a 3rd party python module to check case in-sensitve path?  (windows for me).  its adding bloat to gitlab pipeline, etc..  also ive never heard of that module, and not sure how long it will be around, maintained, etc..  Im using win_stat in my case.  wanting to check for case insensitive path on windows, uncase some moron changes the case on the file.  I may have made a mistake coming here first, wanting to check if win_stat has a case insensitive check.  oops.  Yeah... not seeing it on ansible docs.. still needing a solution for this (without a 3rd party python module).

Comment: Thinking about this, its windows that you cant reuse a case, so im hoping win_stat is smart enough to check case insensitive since its windows...

Comment: Don't remember why I made it with json_query. But if that is your only concern (although it's widely used), you can perfectly drop it here. See my updated answer.